# Can we change styling of angular-material components?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to style angular material components as per my design. I searched internet and didn't find a way to do the same.

Comment: What exactly do you want to change?

Comment: the styling(css) of the components like color, size, etc.

Comment: are you asking about [Theming Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you would like to customise your Angular material components and provide your own stylings, I have the following suggestions. You may use one of them.

1) Overwrite the classes on your main style.css (or style.scss, whichever you are using). If you are wondering, it is the one that is on the same directory level as your `index.html`, `main.ts`, `package.json`, etc. You might need to add the !important declaration

```
.mat-form-field-label {
  color:blue!important;
}
```

2) Use `ViewEncapsulation:None` on that specific component. This removes all encapsulation, such that CSS rules will have a global effect. With that, you can customise the CSS properties by editing the classes on the component.css.

3) Usage of `/deep/`.(However, it is [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)/soon to be deprecated, thus I won't recommend you to use it on the long term)

On your component.ts,

```
:host /deep/ .mat-form-field {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

4) Supplying the directives with a custom class

```
<mat-placeholder class="placeholder">Search</mat-placeholder>
```

And on your css,

```
.placeholder {
  color: green
}
```

Comment: Can you ,tell me how to change color of checkbox of multiselect in angular material?

Comment: @Mohammedkhan actually, yes. You just need to supply the `background-color` attribute of the `.mat-pseudo-checkbox` class with a valid color. I have created a mini demo for you over here (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z8mrgu-c9xjbx?file=styles.css) As you can see, the multi select checkbox colours are blue!

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding the ' encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None ' have worked for me. I think it's overriding the material's style.